# pass array values as parameters of function swift

Tags: arrays, swift3.2

im new to swift.I tried to follow many tutorials but still im not able to find a solution for it.
I want to pass values stored in an array to a function.

```
let trackList = ["AC","BB"]    

for trackId in trackList{

 let ind = trackList.index(of: trackId)
 let index = trackList.startIndex.distance(to: ind!)
 let num = Int(String(describing: ind))
 let track = String(trackId)

 addDiaryList(track:String) //i keep getting error here saying: Cannot convert value of type 'String.Type' to expected argument type 'String'

}

func addDiaryList(track:String) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, the function call is wrong. It should be

```
addDiaryList(track:track!)
```

The first `track` stands for the parameter name in the function, the second one for the variable you assigned two rows above.

But I think you're doing a lot of useless calls here, it could rather be:

```
let trackList = ["AC","BB"]

func addDiaryList(track:String) {
}

for trackId in trackList{
    addDiaryList(track: trackId)
}
```

Comment: Im was still getting error, so I changed into "addDiaryList(track:track!)" and it works.Thanks

Comment: It appears to work only for one element. If another element is added the same error re-appears.

Comment: You have to show more code, I'm not sure what your goal is.